# How can we get a line plot along x or y from a 2D plot?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, data

I have 2D data $f(x,y)$ and would like to get a plot along either of the axes, i.e. $f(x_0,y)$ or $f(x,y_0)$.

```
twoDdata = Table[{x, y, Cos[y ] Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi], \[Pi]/20}, {y, 0, 
2 \[Pi], \[Pi]/20}];
ListDensityPlot[Flatten[twoDdata, 1], ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

what is the best way to get a line plot along the black and brown lines in the Fig above?

here is my idea for the brown one

```
ListLinePlot[twoDdata[[30]][[All, {2, 3}]]]
```

[image]

How can we do it similarly but along the black line? Are there more elegant ways to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or use the 3D version.

```
Clear[c];
twoDdata = 
  Table[{x, y, Cos[y] Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 2 π, π/20}, {y, 0, 
    2 π, π/20}];
c = 3.5; 
ListPlot3D[Flatten[twoDdata, 1], ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}, Mesh -> {{c}}, 
  MeshStyle -> Thick, ViewPoint -> Front, PlotStyle -> None, 
  BoundaryStyle -> None, ViewProjection -> "Orthographic", 
  AxesEdge -> {Automatic, None, Automatic}, 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"] /. {(VertexColors -> None) -> 
   VertexColors -> Automatic}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> How can we do it similarly but along the black line?

I think this does it

```
twoDdata[[All, 20]][[All, {1, 3}]];
ListLinePlot[%]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I picked the 20'th column by inspection as there are 41 columns and this is about half way. If you have specific value for the y coordinates this can be improved.

This is how rowDdata is structured: First row contains all entries related for first $x$ value. Second row contains all entries related to second $x$ value, and so on.

Each row of `rowDdata` in turn is matrix whose each row is for the corresponding $x,y,f(x,y)$ value for that fixed $x$ and changing $y$.

So to pick the samples for the 20's y-value, that will be `twoDdata[[All, 20]]`.  This gives a matrix with 3 entries in each row and has as many entries are there are $x$ values. Then `twoDdata[[All, 20]][[All, {1, 3}]]` picks the $x$ and $f(x,y)$ values from that matrix.